# tcp socket forwarding from multiple sequential clients to a single persistent socket connection to server

Tags: shell-script

I have three programs (A, B, and C). Program C has a tcp socket server waiting for connections on a particular port. Normally program A opens a socket connection to program C, sends it data, then closes the socket, opens the socket again, sends data, closes it, etc. The problem is that each time the socket is opened on C, a lot of initialization is done on program C, so this constant opening and closing of the socket is slowing down A. I don't have the ability to change program A, so I can't change A to make things run faster.

However, what I would like to do, is forward the socket connection from A to a new program B, which will forward the data to program C. Then B can open just one socket to C, and open and close incoming connections from A as needed. I'm looking for a program B to do the following:

```
open socket to C
send request to C to do the time-consuming initialization on C (just this once)
while true
  listen for socket connection from A
  until socket from A is closed
    read data from A, write same data to C
    read data from C, write same data to A
```

This is not a complicated program and I'll write it if necessary, but I was hoping someone has a simple clever solution using existing utilities, or whether there some existing utility that does this sort of thing along with more complicated similar scenarios.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the `nc` tool, provided by the `nc` package on most linux distros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `socat`:

```
mkfifo pipe &&
<pipe socat tcp-listen:"$portB",reuseaddr,fork,bind=localhost - |
  socat - tcp:localhost:"$portC" >pipe
```

Or even better (avoid the fifo and extra layer of interprocess communication):

```
socat "tcp:localhost:$portC" \
      "exec:\"socat - tcp-listen:$portB,reuseaddr,fork,bind=localhost\",nofork"
```

Because of the `nofork`, the second `socat` would run with its stdin and stdout directly connected to the socket to C.